# Limit and quota chrome push-notification limit google-cloud-messaging

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, web-push, push-api

Hello I am working to include push notifications for chrome, basically I  followed  steps https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web although I then added different stuff. Everything works correctly but I have two questions before launching it to all users.

Say first of all that the project where I want to ride is between 60,000 and 200,000 hits a day ... and my idea is that users can subscribe to receive updates in real time, and gradually receive updates according to their interests .

That said, I am not clear whether there are limits to how much I can send push server google ... I read somewhere that is 10,000 a day, but that for this project would be very few, probably in the first day would subscribe to these alerts via push.

Furthermore the subject of active load (Payload), the parameters as documented https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http be added is not working. Basically you can only send the push without active data loading ... somewhat useful, although this is resolved to power set in the "service-worker" A "endpoint" in my case file "php" to being sent to the User cookies to capture the database information itself and mount the push personalized ... but of course this makes sending notifications to many users at the same time that file is about to collapse ... is there any way sending active load? I think that from what I've read is not possible for now

Primarily I need to know the first question, the second I have solved though I wish better off sending data directly.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer for your first question. After migrating from C2DM to GCM, all the limits were [removed](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/c2dm). The only limits that the GCM have can be found in this [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

A note about the limitation(in bold) which can be found in the link is:

> GCM replaces C2DM. The focus of GCM is as follows:
>
> Ease of use. No sign-up forms.
>
> **No quotas.**
>
> GCM and C2DM stats are available through the Developer Console.
>
> Battery efficiency.
> Rich set of new APIs.

For your second question, there are two types of payload: notifications and data payload. Notifications can have up to 2KB while data messages could have up to 4KB. These data messages can be used to process the messages on your Android client app. Refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en#payload) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that there is no quote. (Will update this answer once I've done some digging).

Payloads are in Chrome Version 51 and in Firefox for the past few versions. You can learn more here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption?hl=en

The major gotcha is that you need to encrypt the payload in a specific way which the browser can decrypt, there are libraries being created to help with this: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/push-encryption-node and https://github.com/marco-c/web-push